# Metro Explorer[49987:1068022] Unknown class _TtC14Metro_Explorer7Station in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, swift

I don't even have this class named " _TtC14Metro_Explorer7Station" in my project...Anyone knows how to fix this problem?

[Here are all my files in this project, and a class named station which I used to display the name of stations on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfSY8.png)

[target membership](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJjoU.png)

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide some more information. I've never seen a IB file randomly require classes without something happening. Have you copied an IB file from another project? Try opening the IB file as a text file and search for 'Metro', or just look through it.

Comment: Hi ces, I'm new to swift programming, where can I find my IB file?

Comment: Assuming you're using storyboards, look for Main.storyboard in the main folder. Right-click, Open As->Source Code.

Comment: There's nothing  related to "Metro"..Just "metro explorer", the name of my app's name

Comment: Ok. You'll need to show us a bit more of what you have. Is there a class Station somewhere (or in the storyboard file)? I don't think this is answerable from the information you've given so far.

Comment: I added some information about my project :)

Comment: Is 'Station' referenced in the storyboard? Is 'Station.swift' marked for inclusion in the build target?

Comment: Not in code - in the Storyboard. Check Station.swift is included in the target. Click on the file, look in the Target Membership section of the File Inspector, right hand pane in XCode.

Comment: No, it's not included in the target

Comment: Then include it. Does this fix the problem?

Comment: Very ashamed, but how to include it.

Comment: Just click on the box to check it.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much!!

Comment: Is the problem fixed?

Comment: oh, I'm confused, you said I need to put ‘station.swift’ into Target Membership and check it? I was wondering how to do that? I already have one named 'Metro Explorer' and it has been checked.

Comment: Just needs 'Metro Explorer' to be checked for Station.swift